# Program to Create an image grid dynamically from a folder with images in it

Tags: python, image, automation

I have a folder with a set of images in it. I want to create any type of program that can take in the path of the folder, number of rows and columns and give me output with an image grid. I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: module [pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to read images, resize them and copy/paste them on new image. `sys.argv` to get path and numbers in command line - `python script.py path 2 3`. OR [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) for more complex options in command line. `os.listdir(folder)` or `glob.glob('folder/*.jpg')` to get list of images in folder.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primitive example.

It uses `sys.argv` to get arguments `pattern` instead of `path` (like `"path/*.jpg"`), rows, columns

```
python script 'images/dot-*.png' 2 3
```

It uses module `PIL`/`pillow` to read images, resize them and paste on output image.

---

```
import sys
import glob
from PIL import Image

# for test only
#sys.argv += ['images/dot-*.png', 2, 3]

# get arguments
pattern = sys.argv[1]
rows = int(sys.argv[2])
cols = int(sys.argv[3])

# get filenames
filenames = glob.glob(pattern)

# load images and resize to (100, 100)
images = [Image.open(name).resize((100, 100)) for name in filenames]

# create empty image to put thumbnails
new_image = Image.new('RGB', (cols*100, rows*100))

# put thumbnails
i = 0
for y in range(rows):
    if i >= len(images):
        break
    y *= 100
    for x in range(cols):
        x *= 100
        img = images[i]
        new_image.paste(img, (x, y, x+100, y+100))
        print('paste:', x, y)
        i += 1

# save it
new_image.save('output.jpg')
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Can we add some design to the output and make something like the one in the question. @furas

Comment: you can paste images in different places with different sizes so you can do what you have in question. `pillow` can also draw lines, rectangles, circles, add text - read doc for [pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and [pillow.ImageDraw](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html)

Comment: Thanks ill check that out!

Comment: tried to run your code but the output is a black image.

Comment: did you run it with arguments - `python script.py 'path/*.png' 2 3` ? If you use wrong pattern `'path/*.png'` or `'path/*.jpg'` (or other) then it will not find images and you get empty (black) `output.jpg`. And `path` can be relative or absolut path to folder with images. You can also use `'*.jpg'` if you have images in folder where you run code. BTW: you can add `print(filenames)` to see what it found.